# The program doesn't execute codes after getting user input

Tags: c++

I'm trying to write some content to a file and print it to the console. However, when I execute the codes, the program stops executing the remaining codes after getting the user input. Here is the codes:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main() {
    std::cout << "Password management program: \n";
    std::cout << "1. Save your password \n";
    std::cout << "2. Read your password \n";

    int userChoice;
    std::cout << "Enter your choice: ";
    std::cin >> userChoice;

    // std::cout << "User choice is " << userChoice << "\n";

    int arrSize;
    char str[arrSize];

    if (userChoice == 1) {
        // create a file
        std::fstream pwdFile;
        // open the file & name it
        pwdFile.open("pwd.dat", std::ios::out);

        std::cout << "Enter number of characters for the password: \n";
        std::cin >> arrSize;

        std::cout << "Enter your password: ";

        for (int i=0; i < arrSize; i++) {
            std::cin >> str[i];
            pwdFile << str[i];
        } 

        pwdFile.close();
        std::cout << "Wrote to the file! \n";
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "Wrong choice. Please choose again. \n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Here is the result after running the whole program in the terminal

```
PS D:\_RMIT lectures\Advanced Programming Techniques\NewWorkspace\Tutorial3> g++ exercise1.cpp
PS D:\_RMIT lectures\Advanced Programming Techniques\NewWorkspace\Tutorial3> ./a.exe
Password management program: 
1. Save your password 
2. Read your password 
Enter your choice: 1
PS D:\_RMIT lectures\Advanced Programming Techniques\NewWorkspace\Tutorial3>
```

I have researched in StackOverflow, but I can't still figure out what happened to my codes. What should I do?

Comment: `int arrSize;  char str[arrSize];` is a serious bug. What value is `arrSize` here? Also in standard `c++` an array must be a fixed size at compile time. You probably should just use a `std::string` and avoid char arrays / c-strings when programming in `c++`

Comment: `char str[arrSize];` here you're using `arrsize` before it is even initialized. A C program is not like an Excel sheet, but the statements are executed sequencially. But the overall approach you've taken looks wrong anyway.

Comment: @drescherjm I changed it to `std::string`, and it works. Thanks.

Answer (score -3):

char str[arrSize];
For char array, its length does not accept variable, you may consider using string str to complete your program.

Comment: I did not downvote however the worse problem here is if this code compiles on a compiler with a non-standard VLA extension `arrSize` has not been initialized yet when this code executes. The OP managed to have a compiler that supports a VLA in c++

Comment: I also think so

Comment: Even in that case `int arrSize;  char str[arrSize];` is simply _undefined behavior_ since `arrSize` is uninitialized at that point. Any decent answer should mention this.

Comment: Thank you for your supplementary explanation, I have relatively little experience in answering questions, and the answers will be described in detail in the following questions